# why can't I develop QGIS plugin with c#?

Tags: c#, c++, api, plugins, qgis

I know that QGIS plug-in can be developed with C++ or python.

But I wonder specifically why you can't speak other languages.

First of all, I have no knowledge of programming.

As far as I understand, QGIS is developed in C++, so it cannot be developed in other languages.
But it can also be developed with python.

I am currently studying c#, and I want to develop a QGIS-based application or plug-in using c#.

Please explain in detail the structural reasons that cannot be developed, or give me a link to the document.

If there is no single way to develop QGIS plugin with c#?

Answer (score 5):

QGIS uses Python internally to allow users to script against the application, through its Python API. Using the same Python API, Python plugins can be developed as well. Other scripting languages are not supported (afaik), so the only way you could get them to work is to emulate or call the other scripting language from a Python script.

Similarly, if you write plugins that don't run as a script, but that need to interface with the application directly, you'd be using the C++ ABI and that's specific to the language and even the compiler you're using.

You could possibly write a plugin in C# that implemented that interface to work with QGIS, but the amount of work you'd have to put in to do that probably won't offset the amount of work you expect to save from doing it in C# instead of C++. On top of that, your plugin would likely add a bunch of requirements that aren't requirements for QGIS itself, making its distribution and deployment a pain and possibly giving it a larger footprint than you like.

Just that it can be done, doesn't mean it's a good idea, is the upshot I suppose.

Comment: Having said that - if you write a C# application that can efficiently perform some operation on some data, without requiring direct interaction with parts of QGIS, you could consider writing the interaction with QGIS in Python and calling your C# component from there. However, it still seems like more effort than learning how to do it in C++ (or entirely in Python) and the footprint/requirements issue may remain.